# Python 2.7: can't install/find any dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm running Python 2.7.10 and I can't seem to be able to satisfy any dependencies even after successfully installing them with pip:

```
>python --version
Python 2.7.10
>sudo -H pip install parse
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: parse in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.12.0)
>python myScript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myScript.py", line 3, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Line 3 of my myScript.py looks like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Above my script is complaining that module `parse` can't be found even though I have already installed it using pip. The same is true for other libraries I am trying to use as well.

Why is this?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using sudo (or messing with installing libraries into the system's Python 2). Use `pyenv` and/or get Python3

Answer (score 3):

[`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) is python3, i.e. it looks like your script is for python3

in python2 is [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)

so run it with python3. by now you should be using python3 anyway

as a side note: [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) package that you install is for something different - to parse strings